# Remove unwanted spacing between lines in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview which I use custom font on.

The textview is multiline... The problem is that there's big space between each line to the
other line.

Is there a way to decrease the spacing between lines?

android:lineSpacingExtra Isn't help me, As I need the opposite thing

Comment: Will `android:lineSpacingExtra` accept a negative value?

Comment: omg I feel so stupid. OFC it works :D  thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you could use a negative value in `android:lineSpacingExtra`

Comment: Negative value cut down the below line characters like "g" will be cut down from bottom

Comment: android:lineSpacingExtra falling text in bottom whereas text should be move to top

Answer (score 4):

Adding a negative value for `android:lineSpacingExtra` didn't do anything for me.

Instead I just put any value less than 1.0 for `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` i.e. `android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.7"`