# Android TextView multiline has extra space

Tags: android, textview

Multiline TextViews with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` automatically take up maximum space as if they become `match_parent`. Is there any way keep the true `wrap_content` behavior?

Example xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Example text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Example text ================"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Example text ================"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

1. Single line
2. Multiline
3. How I want it to look

I want to remove the extra space at the left and right ends of the multiline text. The effect can be done if I manually set the `layout_width` to some specific value like `270dp`, but then it becomes arbitrary. I prefer to keep it as `wrap_content`.

EDIT:
The purpose of this is that I want to use a custom background, rounded bg that fits onto the text. I've edited the example xml and the images.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10517044/9119669)

Comment: Found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203729/3273194

Answer (score 0):

Try it programmatically in .java file without changing xml file

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("your content");             
s.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)), 0, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);                     
text.setText(s);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for. But I've edited my question to clarify I want a rounded background on the entire text instead.